# using a pos vector with text in R

Tags: r, text, plot

I'm trying to use [`text`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html) to put some words on my plot. I'd like to use the `pos` parameter in a vector, so I can specify which of words to put (e.g.) above the specified coordinates. But I can't figure out what to put in the vector in order to keep some of the text elements at the specified coordinates! The documentation allows for entries of 1, 2, 3, or 4, each of which moves the text away from the coordinates. What value can I use in my `pos.vector` in order to make no change?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's an example of what I want to do:
At first, I try:

```
radius <- sqrt(z/pi)    
symbols(x,y, circles = radius)
text(z,y,labels=urls)
```

But this produces some overlap in the labels, so I try to include a `pos` vector:

```
pos.vector <- rep(3, length(urls)) #have to use 1, 2, 3, or 4 here
pos.vector[urls %in% c("victoriassecret")] <- 4
radius <- sqrt(z/pi)    
symbols(x,y, circles = z)
text(z,y,labels=urls,pos=pos.vector)
```

But this approach prevents me from keeping the rest of the labels centered, because the `pos` vector only accepts 1, 2, 3 or 4 as inputs. Grr.

Comment: An example would help greatly. I must be so concrete in my thinking that I just cannot figure out what is intended.

Comment: @BondedDust, clarified with an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `text` multiple times through `Map` will get you there, e.g.:

```
pts <- seq(0,1,length.out=4)
plot(pts,pts,pch=19)
Map(text, x=pts, y=pts, labels=letters[1:4], pos=list(4,4,NULL,1))
```

[image]